# How many areas have RVSM being implemented worldwide?

Tags: navigation, rvsm

The data provided by Eurocontrol and latest i could find is of 2003 from internet (source: https://www.slideserve.com/benjamin/cns-1207305 ).
[image: RVSM Worldwide Implementation]

I wanted to know in how many areas still left where RVSM is yet to be implemented.
Any images supporting your answer would be much appreciated.